# Is there a limit to how long a filename URL statement can be?

Tags: sas

I am on design number three I think now of a program that submits a series of stock tickers and metrics to Yahoo Finance. I don't need to go into too much total about what it does as I have got most of it up and running now apart from one remaining issue.

The Yahoo Finance site lists about 2700 stock tickers on the NASDAQ alone. I anticipated that submitting all of these in one filename URL statement might fall over for some reason, so set an initial string length of 500 tickers and built some nested macros to iterate through in 500 ticker blocks until everything I wanted had been extracted.

However during development of the code it seems that if I build a string with any more than about 200 tickers in I get an error telling me that SSL Support cannot be run and the code falls over.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? In ideal world I would like to be able to do this code in one pass where all 2700 stock tickers are pulled down. If this isn't possible if someone could explain why not that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers answers your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Yes that does help. I imagined their would be some kind of system limit placed upon really long URL strings but wasn't sure of the exact reason.